# Create fixed height horizontal div with a fluid one

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to establish a layout with in the base three rows: A header, content and footer div. 
The two outer most div's are of a fixed height; The center div has to be fluid and adapt itself to the height of the browser screen.

[image: Sample of layout]

Could someone point me in the right direction how to tackle this with proper CSS? <strike>For now I'm not yet interested in a javascript solution.</strike> **As CSS doesn't provide a clean answer, a javascript solution comes eminent!**

This is how far I came:

```
<div id='header'>Header</div>
    <div id='content'>
        <div id='innerContent'>
            This is the fluid part
        </div>
    </div>
<div id='footer'>footer</div>
```

css:

```css
#header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100px;
    z-index:5;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100%;
    z-index:2;
}
#innerContent {
    margin-top:100px;
    height:100%;
}
#footer {
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the header and footer to always be in view, regardless of whether or not the main content has been scrolled?

Comment: Nope, they don't have to be fixed to the browser screen!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:
I'm sorry, I feel embarassed. I made something similar about a year ago, but at first I didn't think it was possible to adjust it to this situation. Apparently it was.

As I think other's have already said, it is possible to put the footer div at the bottom by positioning it absolutely. The problem is to adjust it's position when the content div gets larger. Since the footer is absolutely positioned it won't follow the content div's flow, which makes it stay at the same place even though the content expands.

The trick is to wrap everything in an absolutely positioned div. It will expand if it's content gets larger, and the footer div will be positioned according to the wrapper's borders instead of the document's borders.

Here's the code. Try to put a bunch of `<br />` tags within the content div and you'll see that everything adjusts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Layout test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #header {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    #content {
        background-color: gray;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    #footer {
        height: 400px;
        min-width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        margin-bottom: -350px;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id='header'>Header</div>
        <div id='content'>
            Content

        </div>
        <div id='footer'>footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ORIGINAL:
<del>Sadly, css lacks a clean way to do this.</del> You don't know the [viewport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewport) height (which you called h) and therefore can't calculate h-100-50 You have to build your website so that *most* people will see 50px of the footer div. The way to do that is to set a min-height for the content div.

The min-height value must be derived from some standard viewport height. Google Labs have published their data on viewport sizes for their visitors and made a great visualization of it here:
http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/

I design for my own viewport, which is 620px high (according to google ~80% have this viewport height). Therefore the min-height for the content div should be 620-100-50 = 470 px.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Layout test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #header {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    #content {
        min-height: 470px;
        background-color: gray;
    }

    #footer {
        height: 400px;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='header'>Header</div>
    <div id='content'>
        Content
    </div>
    <div id='footer'>footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a height defined for all of it.

Comment: +1 for referencing googles statistics, and a nice clean answer.  It's worth noting that if JavaScript is allowed, a script can be written and bound to the browser resize event to ensure the content is always 100% of its size, less the header/footer.  Like you stated though, CSS doesn't handle this on its own, yet.

Comment: @Starx I'm not sure what you mean with "all of it"?

Comment: @LarsNyström, I meant all the divisions top, center and bottom one.

Comment: Thank you for the clean and elaborated answer +1 What Starx means is that if the browser window gets resized the content div will stay the same height.
I might redesign the layout......

Comment: Yeah, thats the problem. But I don't know another way.

Comment: @Starx the content div doesnt have a fixed height, only a minimum height.

Comment: I've added the solution to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly I think this might lead you into the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/mikevoermans/r6Saq/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a poke at it.  Not sure if I read your screenshot correctly but I set the content div to be 50-100px in height.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AX5Bh/

I am using the `min-height` and `max-height` CSS attributes to control the `#innerContent` div.

If you horizontally expand the result window you will see that some of the text is highlighted  .  I have set the content to be hidden if it is larger than the `#innerContent` div.  You might want something different.  I only highlighted the text with an `<em>` tag to demonstrate that `max-height` was working.

If you remove all the text but the first sentence you will see it is 50px in height.

Here is a link to browser support of `min-height` and `max-height`: http://caniuse.com/#search=max-height